# SQL: Compare order by location to average of all orders

Tags: sql, sql-server, average, outer-join

I'm trying to show the average order amount for each location and show how many order have a value for that location greater than the average of all the location.  I tried doing the comparison using a subquery and got "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery."  Ok, so then I through I could do an Outer Apply with the subquery and compare it, but it will not bind the values.  I'm unable to figure it out and could use some help.  Here's my latest query:

```
SELECT 
    PUE.LocID, 
    PUE.Name, 
    IsNull(sum(PUOS.Quantity),0) as [Quantity], 
    AVG((PUOS.Quantity * PUOS.UnitPrice)) AS [Avg Order Value], 
    sum(
        case when (PUOS.Quantity * PUOS.UnitPrice) > 
                AVG((Quantity.LocAvg * UnitPrice.LocAvg)) Then 1 
        else 0 end) 
    AS [Greater Loc Avg]
FROM Locations PUE
    OUTER APPLY (select AVG((Quantity * UnitPrice)) as Avg from Sales
                    WHERE CONVERT(date,SaleDate) <= '2014-11-30' 
                        AND PackageID <> 999  
                        AND LocID > 7598 
                        AND LocID < 7622) LocAvg
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Sales PUOS 
        ON PUOS.LocID = PUE.LocID and 
            CONVERT(date,PUOS.SaleDate) <= '2014-11-30' 
                AND PUOS.PackageID <> 999  
            WHERE PUE.LocID > 7598
                AND PUE.LocId < 7622
                AND PUE.GroupID = 473
GROUP BY PUE.LocID, PUE.Name
ORDER BY PUE.LocID, PUE.Name;
```

This doesn't work because: The multi-part identifier "Quantity.LocAvg" could not be bound.
The multi-part identifier "UnitPrice.LocAvg" could not be bound.  I tried using Avg.LocAvg that give the same error.  I'm sure there an easier way to do this, but it's not coming to me and my Google-Fu is not helping either.

Comment: You do not have Quantity in your from clause, neither as a table or an alias.

Comment: Looks like `Quantity` and `UnitPrice` were column names

Comment: Quantity and UnitPrice are column names...  I guess I'm not following.

Comment: Then you cannot use `Quantity.LocAvg` it is like `Columnname.columname` which is not allowed. It should be either **table alias name or table name dot column name** like `tablename.columnname`

Comment: Man, I knew that...  I should have caught that.  Thanks NoDisplayName!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NoDisplayName is correct, I revered the Alias...  I just replaced AVG((Quantity.LocAvg * UnitPrice.LocAvg)) with LocAvg.Avg and it worked just fine.  I feel stupid.